# return a value from a dynamic mysql and update a table with

Tags: mysql, sql-update, dynamic-programming

I am working on an automatisation of queries in my database. I have 15 tables names the same way 'blablablaCOUNTRYblablabla' and i want to count the number of rows of each table and store them into an other table that actually contains just the list of the countries and and the table name.

I have decided to create a procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT USER PROCEDURE `PM`()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE nom_table VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE site_table_uniq VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE x INT;
DECLARE nb_ligne INT;
DECLARE site_coord VARCHAR(1000);

SET nom_table = "";
SET site_table_uniq = "";
SET x = 1;
SET nb_ligne = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIG_PM_THERMO);
# SIG PM THERMO is the table i want to fill with the number of rows

WHILE x <= nb_ligne DO
    SET site_table_uniq = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = x);

    SET @site_coord = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_coord FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = 1) ;
    
    SET @nom_table = (SELECT pm.Nom_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pm WHERE pm.Site_table = site_table_uniq );
            
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(nb_therm) FROM (SELECT COUNT(pmt.Temperature) AS nb_therm FROM ', @nom_table,' pmt WHERE pmt.Temperature !="-99" ) AS t ;');


    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;       
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;        
    
    SET x = x + 1;

END WHILE; 

END
```

This display (each value in a tab with one line) all the value i need but i don't understand how to get them and store them in my table with a condition (that the countries are the same)

Would have any idea ?

Best regards (and happy new year)

Answer (score 0):

You rewrite your query a little and add a varianble that stores the data

Every loop  adds the session variable  @sumthermo  to the tolasum which is stored in an OUT variable

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `PM`(OUT _totalsum BIGINT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE nom_table VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE site_table_uniq VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE x INT;
DECLARE nb_ligne INT;
DECLARE site_coord VARCHAR(1000);
SET _totalsum := 0;
SET nom_table = "";
SET site_table_uniq = "";
SET x = 1;
SET nb_ligne = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIG_PM_THERMO);
# SIG PM THERMO is the table i want to fill with the number of rows

WHILE x <= nb_ligne DO
    SET site_table_uniq = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = x);

    SET @site_coord = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_coord FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = 1) ;
    
    SET @nom_table = (SELECT pm.Nom_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pm WHERE pm.Site_table = site_table_uniq );
            
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(nb_therm) INTO @sumthermo FROM (SELECT COUNT(pmt.Temperature) AS nb_therm FROM ', @nom_table,' pmt WHERE pmt.Temperature !="-99" ) AS t ;');

    SET _totalsum := _totalsum + @sumthermo ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;       
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;        
    
    SET x = x + 1;

END WHILE; 

END
```

Now you can run the query and have the value stored in another sessionvariable

```
CALL PM(@totalsum);
```

What you also can do is save all the sums in another session varialble

```
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `PM`()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE nom_table VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE site_table_uniq VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE x INT;
DECLARE nb_ligne INT;
DECLARE site_coord VARCHAR(1000);

SET nom_table = "";
SET site_table_uniq = "";
SET x = 1;
SET nb_ligne = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIG_PM_THERMO);
# SIG PM THERMO is the table i want to fill with the number of rows

WHILE x <= nb_ligne DO
    SET site_table_uniq = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = x);

    SET @site_coord = (SELECT pmthermo.Site_coord FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pmthermo WHERE pmthermo.Id = 1) ;
    
    SET @nom_table = (SELECT pm.Nom_table FROM SIG_PM_THERMO pm WHERE pm.Site_table = site_table_uniq );
            
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(nb_therm) INTO @sumthermo FROM (SELECT COUNT(pmt.Temperature) AS nb_therm FROM ', @nom_table,' pmt WHERE pmt.Temperature !="-99" ) AS t ;');

    SET @totalsum := @totalsum + @sumthermo ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;       
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;        
    
    SET x = x + 1;

END WHILE; 

END
```

Now you only execute the procudre with
call PM();

and have also the values in @totalsum

The OUT variable is preferable, when you use python or other languages, that can run stored procedures

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you mean although when I add 'INTO' in my query, the result is 'NULL' (which isn't suppose to be) and even if I give manually a number ..

Comment: then is something else wrong but the query works just as expected see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9c52c15ef768a0455c0c646ba02d22c